# Canadian nomad, USD earnings - how to invest/preserve currency

Tags: canada, brokerage, financial-advisor, foreign-currency, robo-advisor

I'm a Canadian tax resident who moves around a lot. Exchanging currency stresses me out so much if I think about it that I basically have just decided to accept volatility.
I work online, and am paid USD. For a long time, this was deposited into my CDN bank account and again, I just accepted what the currency was doing at that time. However if I was traveling out of the country, which was often, I'd then be converting currency again (side note: I don't use credit cards- got myself in trouble years ago and now it's only cash/debit.) 
I got myself a cross-border account with TD, so now my pay stays in USD. I convert only what I need into CDN. I also have a USD account domiciled in Canada.

---

Now, I want to do something "smart" with what is currently just sitting in USD account. It is not much. Certainly no broker is going to be interested. That makes it hard to get advice. I would like to use an online broker and buy ETFs in USD. (at least that's what I have concluded thus far)
With that background, my questions are these:

1. Recommended Canadian brokerage that has low fees/ low minimum (i can start with $2500) and will keep the USD as is.
2. Tax implications and where/how  (i know this is not a simple question): I understand TFSA might be wise, but I understand that if I want to withdraw, it will THEN be converted to Canadian. There is a good chance I will need to cash out for a big move in the next year or 2 and I don't want to risk the loonie being strong.
3. Recommendations for an advisor (or how to find one) for someone in my situation. I would not object to paying for a consultation if it can get me on solid footing

Comment: When do you intend to return to Canada (if ever)? This will impact whether you actually should want any CAD preservation or not, and whether your tax strategy will be effective.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are off-topic. Suggest you edit your question to focus on the parts that are on-topic.

Comment: Given you already have an account with TD (Toronto Dominion Bank?) Cant you invest through them. I know they are a low cost brokerage in the US and UK, and I presume they must be in Canada too... They offer a wide variety of index ETFs from what I recall.